# SSH commands work in console, but not inside of bash script - how to diagnose?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a bash script that executes multiple ssh commands and have ran into a problem. I've been working on adding automatic ssh key generation for the script and am having a weird error where the ssh commands work when manually typed through the console but do not work inside the script.

The series of commands is as follows. (Key generation > checking for remote script > executing remote script)

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" > ~/.ssh/config
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' <<< ""$'\n'"y" 2>&1 >/dev/null
sshpass -f password.txt ssh-copy-id user@x.x.x.x
ssh user@x.x.x.x "test -e /home/user/script.sh"
ssh user@x.x.x.x "echo password | sudo -S /home/user/script.sh > log.txt"
```

This works flawlessly in the console, but suddenly in the script it doesn't work. The only difference is that in the script there are some echos to append data to a log, which shouldn't impact the ssh commands.

The first ssh command works `ssh user@x.x.x.x "test -e /home/user/script.sh"`, however the second command `ssh user@x.x.x.x "echo password | sudo -S /home/user/script.sh > log.txt"` does not. It receives connection refused 6 times and returns an exit of 255 usually. Below is a sample log when it is ran with the -v flag.

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection refused
```

And the ps aux when its ran.

```
ps aux | grep ssh
root      1287  0.0  0.3  65504  6500 ?        Ss   Sep18   0:02 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      4409  0.0  0.0  14220   888 pts/0    S+   11:14   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
root     20680  0.0  0.3  94860  6900 ?        Ss   09:09   0:00 sshd: user [priv]
user    20760  0.0  0.1  94860  3540 ?        S    09:09   0:00 sshd: user@notty
user    20761  0.0  0.1  12876  2000 ?        Ss   09:09   0:00 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
root     21024  0.0  0.3  94860  7052 ?        Ss   08:13   0:00 sshd: user [priv]
user    21133  0.0  0.2  94860  4636 ?        R    08:13   0:04 sshd: user@pts/0
```

**So my question is, how can I accurately diagnose and fix this issue?**

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is in `script.sh`?

Comment: @cutrightjm script.sh is just a script that contains a bunch of commands to help monitor the remote machine. Prints uptime, system alarms, cpu usage, etc

Comment: Does the `user@x.x.x.x` have sudo rights on the remote machine? Also, you mentioned it worked into you threw some echos in? What log file are those echos writing to. The SSH output seems to indicate that there is no appropriate key for the user of the remote machine on your box

Comment: The debug log indicates that  the script is trying to connect as root (`/root/.ssh/config`), whereas your interactive testing looks like it is being performed as an unprivileged user. Are you running the script with `sudo` by any chance?

Comment: @cutrightjm In regards to the echos, I meant the only difference between my interactive testing and the script is that the script has a few echos writing to a log (contained in the home directory). The user is not privileged which is why the command is using `echo pass | sudo -S` as the remote script needs to be ran as the superuser. Logging in as root is disabled on the remote machine.

Comment: @steeldriver I am running the local script as sudo

Comment: Where possible use keys over passwords. Passwords are easier to hack and harder to script.

Comment: This is a long shot, but make sure the second `ssh user@x.x.x.x...` command doesn't have a typo in the hostname/IP part.

Comment: `sudo` specifically checks for "is `STDIN` a pipe, not a keyboard?" and disallows it, and sees NO input.

Comment: @Kenster Yeah its not that haha, the script uses the same ip and username (as variables) earlier in the script with no problem

Comment: @waltinator Does this behavior change when sshed into a remote machine? The same commands works fine on local.

Comment: So the script in the question isn’t the actual script? Please [edit] your question to show the actual script that you are running.